# Диррективно-комиссивный акт

Tags: недопустимая-метка, терминология

Коллеги, помогите пожалуйста парочкой примеров директивно-комиссивных актов, желательно из книг или фильмов. И вобще нигде не могу найти его точную формулировку((

Answer (score 2):

Точных определений не помню,но где-то так:

Директив:требования, просьбы, приказы, указания, инструкции, распоряжения, установление норм.

Комиссив: обещания, объявления, угрозы,т.е. обязательства, которые говорящий принимает на себя.

Сразу как-то примеры на ум не приходят.Что-то вроде"Уйди с глаз моих, а то я..."